# How do I verify mocked async method called with correct expression?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit, xunit.net

I have written some tests using XUnit and Moq. One method of the mocked interface implementation is accepting a parameter of type `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`  Everything seems to be working well but I have trouble understanding the working of verifying that the method is called with the right expression.

Given the following test, the method does not return the value specified in the setup, even though the call seems correct.:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Verify that a create fails appropriately when another entity was found given the same name,
    /// Verify that the message of the exception contains the duplicate name
    /// Verify that update fails before other calls are made
    /// </summary>
    [Theory(DisplayName = "Definition Types service - Create")]
    [MemberData(nameof(DefinitionTypesTestData.SingleDefinitionType), MemberType = typeof(DefinitionTypesTestData))]
    public async Task CreateDefinitionTypeShouldThrowDuplicateTest(DefinitionType obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) throw new NullReferenceException($"Test data was null in theory 'Definition Types service - Create'");
        var crudService = new Mock<IEntityCrudService<DefinitionType>>();
        crudService.Setup(crud => crud.GetEntitiesAsync(x => x.Name == obj.Name))
            .Returns(Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<DefinitionType>>(new List<DefinitionType> {
            new DefinitionType {
                Name = "Test",
                Description = "Test",
                DisplayName = "Test",
                ID = Guid.NewGuid()
            } }));
        IDefinitionTypesService serviceUnderTest = new DefinitionTypesService(crudService.Object);
        var exception = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<EntityDuplicationException>(() => serviceUnderTest.InsertDefinitionTypeAsync(obj));
        Assert.Contains("Definition type", exception.DisplayMessage);
        Assert.Contains(obj.Name, exception.DisplayMessage);
        crudService.Verify(crud => crud.GetEntitiesAsync(x => x.Name == obj.Name), Times.Once);
        crudService.VerifyNoOtherCalls();
    }
```

I have the following implementation for InsertDefinitionType(DefinitionType obj):

```
async Task IDefinitionTypesService.InsertDefinitionTypeAsync(DefinitionType obj)
    {
        var definitiontypes = await _definitionTypeService.GetEntitiesAsync(x => x.Name == obj.Name);

        if(definitiontypes.Any())
        {
            throw new EntityDuplicationException("Definition type", name: obj.Name);
        }

        try
        {
            await _definitionTypeService.CreateAsync(obj);
        }
        catch (EntityNotSavedException exc)
        {
            exc.EntityType = "Definition type";
            throw exc;
        }
    }
```

When I change my setup as follows I do get the result, but in my verify function it says the function is never called (or at least with the given expression). :

```
crudService.Setup(crud => crud.GetEntitiesAsync(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<DefinitionType, bool>>>()))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<DefinitionType>>(new List<DefinitionType> {
        new DefinitionType {
            Name = "Test",
            Description = "Test",
            DisplayName = "Test",
            ID = Guid.NewGuid()
        } }));
```

Right now I have also changed the verification to be more generic:

```
crudService.Verify(crud => crud.GetEntitiesAsync(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<DefinitionType, bool>>>()), Times.Once);
```

Now my test passes, but I really want to verify the method is called correctly instead of being called at all. How do I solve this the easiest / best way?

Answer (score 4):

You will need to be more specific about the expression used in the setup.

Use `It.Is<T>()` and invoked the expression for the setup and verification.

```
[Theory(DisplayName = "Definition Types service - Create")]
[MemberData(nameof(DefinitionTypesTestData.SingleDefinitionType), MemberType = typeof(DefinitionTypesTestData))]
public async Task CreateDefinitionTypeShouldThrowDuplicateTest(DefinitionType obj) {

    if (obj == null) throw new NullReferenceException($"Test data was null in theory 'Definition Types service - Create'");

    //Arrange
    var crudService = new Mock<IEntityCrudService<DefinitionType>>();

    var list = new List<DefinitionType>() {
        new DefinitionType {
            Name = "Test",
            Description = "Test",
            DisplayName = "Test",
            ID = Guid.NewGuid()
        }
    };

    crudService
        .Setup(_ => _.GetEntitiesAsync(It.Is<Expression<Func<DefinitionType, bool>>>(exp => exp.Compile()(obj))))
        .ReturnsAsync(list);

    IDefinitionTypesService serviceUnderTest = new DefinitionTypesService(crudService.Object);

    //Act
    var exception = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<EntityDuplicationException>(() => serviceUnderTest.InsertDefinitionTypeAsync(obj));

    //Assert
    Assert.Contains("Definition type", exception.DisplayMessage);
    Assert.Contains(obj.Name, exception.DisplayMessage);
    crudService.Verify(_ => _.GetEntitiesAsync(It.Is<Expression<Func<DefinitionType, bool>>>(exp => exp.Compile()(obj))), Times.Once);
    crudService.VerifyNoOtherCalls();
}
```

Pay special attention to the expression used in the setup and verification.

```
_ => _.GetEntitiesAsync(It.Is<Expression<Func<DefinitionType, bool>>>(exp => exp.Compile()(obj)))
```

Comment: Hi Nkosi, thanks for your answer. I don't think I understand it quite well, sorry if I'm a noob. How can I specify the expression itself (i.e. `x => x.Name == obj.Name`) and verify it is called given the right parameters? I see the lambda compiling the expression. But doesn't this work for any given expression? I explicitly want to set the expression itself in the setup and verify the same expression. I read that expressions are not easily comparable because they are reference types and that you will need to write some logic for comparing. This looks far easier but I don't see this fit yet.